# Display all men from a file on the screen in C

Tags: c, file, structure

I'm a newbie in C.
Could you help me please. There is a structure First name, Last Name, gender, age. Entries must be entered from the keyboard. I need to save this information in a file and then show on the screen all entries with gender == Male and save them in a separate file.
Thank you!

There is a code for reading a structure from file, but I can't understand how to check gender == Male.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdio>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE *file;
    struct Person {
        char name[20]; 
        char gender[20]; 
        unsigned age; 
    };
    struct Person SinglePerson[10];
    char i=0;

    file = fopen("e:\\Test.txt", "r");

    while (fscanf (file, "%s%s%u", SinglePerson[i].name, &(SinglePerson[i].gender), &(SinglePerson[i].age)) != EOF) {
        printf("%s %s %u\n", SinglePerson[i].name, SinglePerson[i].gender, SinglePerson[i].age); 
        i++;
    }

    file = fopen("e:\\fprintf.txt", "w");

    while (scanf ("%s%s%u", SinglePerson[i].name, &(SinglePerson[i].gender), &(SinglePerson[i].age)) != EOF) {
        fprintf(file, "%s %s %u\n", SinglePerson[i].name, SinglePerson[i].gender, SinglePerson[i].age); 
        i++;
    }
    fread;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `fopen` to open the file, `fwrite` to write the struct, `fread` to read.

Comment: @cdarke, could you add more details... How to check that gender == male?

Comment: Could you add code that is actually the code you're working on and not some random code that has nothing to do with it?

Comment: Don't you have any `man` pages or documentation you can look at for basic information?\

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thank you and sorry... This a worked code. The previous code from another task.

Comment: @cdarke sorry for it. This is a true code.

Comment: Look at the parameters for `read` and `write` on the `man` pages.

Comment: @cdarke, I already look, but how I have no clue how to compare it...

Comment: You don't need the fread and fwrite if you are using scan and printf.

Answer (score 1):

Worked! I did it ))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define M 2 // M plus 1 is equals to number of structres

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

    FILE *file;
    struct Person {
        char name[20]; 
        char gender[20]; 
        unsigned age; 
    };
    struct Person SinglePerson[1];
    char i=0;
    char counter = 0;

void InputFromKeyboard () {
    file = fopen("Input.txt", "w");
    while(scanf("%s%s%u", SinglePerson[i].name, SinglePerson[i].gender, &(SinglePerson[i].age)) == 3 && i <= M) {
        fprintf(file, "%s %s %u\n", SinglePerson[i].name, SinglePerson[i].gender, SinglePerson[i].age); 
        counter++;
        i++;
        if (i == M+1) {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
};

void OutputToFile () {
    file = fopen("Output.txt", "w");
    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        if (strcmp(SinglePerson[i].gender, "Male") == 0) {
            fprintf(file, "%s %s %u\n", SinglePerson[i].name, SinglePerson[i].gender, SinglePerson[i].age); 
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}

void OutputToScreen () {
    file = fopen("Output.txt", "r");
    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        if (strcmp(SinglePerson[i].gender, "Male") == 0) {
            printf("%s %s %u\n", SinglePerson[i].name, SinglePerson[i].gender, SinglePerson[i].age); 
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    InputFromKeyboard();
    OutputToFile();
    OutputToScreen();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good job you figured it out! A better test would be with more than one entry. Best make `i` a local variable in the functions where it gets used.  Also do remove the opening and closing a file in `InputFromKeyboard`.

Comment: @Jongware Thank you a lot! Could add a little bit more details about InputFromKeyboard?

Comment: Um. It seems you needed that after all, as an example of the original input file. Ignore please.